# JCalendar-component on Netbeans 18 not working on MacOS, but working on PC

Tags: java, macos, swing, netbeans, jcalendar

In Netbeans on my Mac, the JCalendar-component on the palette shows an empty icon with a question mark.

[error-png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kYQQ.jpg)

I followed these steps to install it:
Manage Pallete > Add From Jar > Select JCalendar > Select Category > Finish

Following the same steps on my Windows PC works without problems and JCalendar appears on the palette.

I am using Apache NetBeans 18. My Java version is ...

How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue in Netbeans on my Mac.